# Creating a function to brighten or darken colors

Tags: functions

I want to create a function $f : [0,255]^3 \rightarrow [0,255]^3$ over the integers such that if you pass in three RGB color values, a triple with a darker or lighter color will be returned, and I want the values to increase in some sort of proportion to how dark or light they are already; lightness and darkness being determined by, say, taking the average of the values.

Is there a relatively simple function that will do this? If not, is there a way to emulate it?

Comment: Why not convert to HSB, perform the operations there, and convert back?

Comment: There is a bijection used by my dad when he taught elementary school to scale grades, which can be modified to be $h(x) = 16 * \sqrt{x}$ for $x\in [0,256]$. You can perform this entry-wise on RGB. To change the dependence on the starting value, you can change $\sqrt{x}$ to $|x|^p$ for $p < 1$.

Comment: [real-analysis] is inappropriate. [functions] seems inappropriate too, but I have left that in.

Comment: @Willie: In image processing, they call that [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction).

Comment: @Rahul: Thanks! Learned something new everyday.

Comment: @[Rahul , Willie Wong]: Thank you both, I learned something too.

Comment: @Willie (I apologize for the late response) if you make that an answer I would be happy to accept it as such!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This *was* a comment. Posting as CW answer so the question can be marked as solved.)

There is a bijection used by my dad when he taught elementary school to scale grades, which can be modified to be $h(x)=16 \sqrt{x}$ for $x\in [0,256]$. You can perform this entry-wise on RGB. To change the dependence on the starting value, you can change $\sqrt{x}$ to $|x|^p$ for $p<1$.

(And as Rahul pointed out in the comments, the above is nothing but [gamma correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction). )